# Searching for multiple text patterns in R

Tags: r

This question is related to: [Searching a data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799614/searching-a-data-frame-in-r/25799678?noredirect=1#comment40355039_25799678)

I want to search for multiple patterns , e.g. 'america' and 'united', in

1. all fields
2. in a given field

How can this be done? The case needs to be ignored.

Data:

```
ddf
  id                  country          area
1  1 United States of America North America
2  2           United Kingdom        Europe
3  3     United Arab Emirates          Arab
4  4             Saudi Arabia          Arab
5  5                   Brazil South America

ddf = structure(list(id = 1:5, country = c("United States of America", 
"United Kingdom", "United Arab Emirates", "Saudi Arabia", "Brazil"
), area = c("North America", "Europe", "Arab", "Arab", "South America"
)), .Names = c("id", "country", "area"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

EDIT: To clarify, I have to search with AND and not OR. In this example, only 'United States of America' (row number 1) should come. If I search for 'brazil' and 'america', row number 5 should come (i.e. different search strings can be in different columns).

Answer (score 3):

This actually fails for the "brazil" & "america" case but it was a useful test-bed for diagnosisng the logical problems;

```
hasAm <-  sapply( ddf, grepl, patt="america", ignore.case=TRUE)
ddf[ rowSums(hasAm) > 0 , ]
#----------
  id                  country          area
1  1 United States of America North America
5  5                   Brazil South America
#---------
hasUn <- sapply( ddf, grepl, patt="united", ignore.case=TRUE)
#---------
ddf[ rowSums( hasAm & hasUn) > 0 , ]
#-----------
  id                  country          area
1  1 United States of America North America
```

This edited version generalizes that strategy although it requires entering the selection criteria as a formula. I needed to first collapse each matrix so that summing across the cbind()-ed values didn't pick up multiple hits on a single term. So I have two rowSums, the outer one being done on *m*-column matrices where *m* is the number of terms in the formula, and the inner one being done on *n*-column matrices where *n* is the number of columns in the data-argument:

```
 dfsel <- function(form, data) { 
       vars = all.vars(form)    
       selmatx <- lapply( vars, function(v)
                              sapply (data,  grepl, patt=v, ignore.case=TRUE)) 
       data[ rowSums( do.call(cbind, 
                          lapply(selmatx, 
                              function(L) {rowSums(L) > 0}) ) ) == length(vars)
              , ]  }
```

Demonstration:

```
> res <- dfsel( ~ united + america , ddf)
> res
  id                  country          area
1  1 United States of America North America

> res <- dfsel( ~ brazil + america , ddf)
>  res
  id country          area
5  5  Brazil South America
```

Comment: I've been trying to improve my facilities in "computing on the language".

Comment: If I search for 'brazil' and 'america', row number 5 should come: that is not happening here.

Comment: And the same test leads to failure with the earlier version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Dumb way of solving it. Interested in other answers.

```
pattern<-c('America','United')
ddf1<-NULL
for (i in 1:length(pattern)){
  new<-ddf[grep(paste0(pattern[i]),ddf$country),]
  ddf1<-rbind(ddf1,new)
}
```

Comment: If you check the output for dd1, 'United States of America' is coming twice. Also I have to search with AND and not OR.

Comment: thanks. I didnt check on that part. `unique` would be the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Going on the logic that no country in the world has "America" before "United" in its name, you could do

```
> f <- lapply(ddf, grep, pattern = "(united)(.*)(america)", ignore.case = TRUE)
> ddf[unique(unlist(f)), ]
#   id                  country          area
# 1  1 United States of America North America
```

Comment: I have to search with AND and not OR.